# How to share webcam frames with server in a efficient way for a website

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

I need to share the webcam frames with server. I'm newbie in this. Currently I'm doing this by drawing it on `canvas` and sending the `Base64` string of the image to the server using `fetch` API. Is there any other method which can do it quickly and efficiently.

```
        var width = 320; // We will scale the photo width to this
        var height = 0; // This will be computed based on the input stream

        var streaming = false;

        var video = null;
        var canvas = null;
        var photo = null;
        var startbutton = null;

        function startup() {
            video = document.getElementById('video');
            canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            photo = document.getElementById('photo');
            startbutton = document.getElementById('startbutton');

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    video: true,
                    audio: false
                })
                .then(function(stream) {
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.play();
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
                });

            video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev) {
                if (!streaming) {
                    height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / width);

                    if (isNaN(height)) {
                        height = width / (4 / 3);
                    }

                    video.setAttribute('width', width);
                    video.setAttribute('height', height);
                    canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
                    canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
                    streaming = true;
                }
            }, false);

            startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
                takepicture();
                ev.preventDefault();
            }, false);

            clearphoto();
        }


        function clearphoto() {
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
            context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            photo.setAttribute('src', data);
        }

        function takepicture() {
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            if (width && height) {
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

                var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                console.log(data);
                sendImage(data);
                photo.setAttribute('src', data);
            } else {
                clearphoto();
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', startup, false);

    function  sendImage(dataURL){
      fetch('/recognize', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({imageBase64:dataURL})
      }).then(res=>res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res));
          }
```

Comment: You may want to [compress the image with gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943481/enabling-gzip-compression-with-fetch-js) before sending it to the server.

Comment: What about using webrtc ,Is it better?

Comment: Setting up webrtc is quite involved and complicated. It's designed for peer-to-peer communication without using an intermediate server, not client-to-server communication.